# Angular material : Navigation schematics doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-schematics

I want to create angular material navigation schematics.
when i run
ng generate @angular/material:navigation   command it gives error.

The 'path' option in 'C:\Users\Pradeepa saravanan\Documents\TS\HotelInventoryApp\node_modules@angular\material\schematics\ng-generate\navigation\schema.json' is using deprecated behaviour. 'workingDirectory' smart default provider should be used instead.
(0 , validation_1.validateName) is not a function

After that i update angular material using     ng update @angular/material  command. Again i got some error.

The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 15.0.4 to perform the update.
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 30 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Updating multiple major versions of '@angular/material' at once is not supported. Please migrate each major version individually.
Run 'ng update @angular/material@14' in your workspace directory to update to latest '14.x' version of '@angular/material'.

After I run  'ng update @angular/material@14' command, again getting error

```
Packages successfully installed.
Using package manager: npm
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 30 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
× Migration failed: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fCLI - Not found
  See "C:\Users\PRADEE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-aPCtDl\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Help me to solve the issue

I tried to add angular material navigation schematics. continuously i got error and not able to solve myself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when working on an Angular project that used version `14`, and the cli installed uses a later version temporarily to execute the command, luckily, I had the option to upgrade my application using the guide provided [here](https://update.angular.io/).

When the CLI version was 16, and the project (package.json) reflect version 16 I could use the command without any issues.